# Kivy-ios sdl2 run on ios in low resolution

Tags: ios, iphone, resolution, kivy, sdl-2

Anyone had problem with new kivy-ios toolchain (with 64bit support) and low resolution? On earlier kivy-ios version (build_all.sh) resolution on iPhone was fine.
Tested on simulator in xcode also on iPhone 4s device - screen resolution is forced to 320x480.

Screenshots:
http://www.send-picture.com/img-54febd75a9982.html#.VP69elRGjUY

In output got:

```
[INFO              ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2 ('MODE', 320, 480) ('DRAWABLE SIZE', 320, 480)
```

I've already tried to add loading screens with required dimensions - didn't helped. 
Please help.

Comment: After merging kivy branches (master and  ios-poly-arch) low resolution issue has gone. https://github.com/kivy/kivy/commit/f5d24e39b5d1836bdfc16a0525523948b4d44e8d