# New kivy-Ios toolchain, application crashes when portrait orientation is disabled

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I tried to create package for iOS 8.2 using new kivy-ios toolchain on OS X 10.9.5. Unfortunately when I disable 'Portrait' orientation in 'Deployment Info' xcode 6.2, application crashes with following output:

```
2015-03-11 04:48:32.449 testapp[1478:44792] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [SDLLaunchScreenController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f245a75 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010edcebb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f2459ad +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   UIKit                               0x000000010ce4a263 -[UIViewController __supportedInterfaceOrientations] + 644
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010ce3f9e3 -[UIViewController _preferredInterfaceOrientationGivenStatusBarAndDeviceAndOrientation:] + 64
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010cd55b43 -[UIWindow setRootViewController:] + 103
    6   testapp                             0x000000010b940a25 -[SDLUIKitDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 413
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010cd0b458 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 248
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010cd0c002 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2540
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010cd0ee3e -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1349
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010cd0dd35 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    11  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000112a62243 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f17ac7c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f1709c5 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f170785 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f16fbc6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010cd0d7a2 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010cd10580 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    18  testapp                             0x000000010b93fa9b main + 203
    19  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011037f145 start + 1
    20  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I have done test on iPhone 5s and iOS symulator, both gave me same results.

It worked fine before, on old kivy-ios toolchain, iOS 8.1 and xcode 6.1. The new iOS and xcode is quite new now so I can't find any answer. Only thing I found is this question [Kivy-ios sdl2 run on ios in low resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28960714/kivy-ios-sdl2-run-on-ios-in-low-resolution/28978350#28978350) about low resolution which is another problem that I have too after upgrade.

Comment: Have you reported a issue? New tool chain is bound to have some issues.

Comment: I'll try on fresh Yosemite today and if it fail I'll report issue as you said. Thanks.